# Is $A \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(A)$ injective when $A = \{\}$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is $A \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(A)$ injective or not?

Here $A = \{\}$ and $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{\{\}\}$.

Using the definition of injective function: A function is $f : X \rightarrow Y ; \forall x \in X, \forall y \in X, (f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y)$

Using the definition of power set: set containing all of the subsets of the set

I am wondering if this is *vacuously* true because $f \subset A \times \mathcal{P}(A)$ the cartesian product with empty set is itself. Therefore it is injective.

Is it right or I am wrong, how to fix it.

Comment: Yes, the empty function is vacuously injective.

Comment: @runway44, so my work is correct then? 

I always wonder why is the "empty function is vacuously injective"? I never got the why it is like that.

Comment: Any statement of the form $\forall x\in\varnothing,P(x)$ is called "vacuously" true because it is only true by virtue of there not existing any $x$s to be counterexamples in the first place. (The way to interpret the for all statement, for the empty set, is to rephrase it as $\not\exists x\in\varnothing,\neg P(x)$.)

Comment: For a function $f:A\to B$ to be non-injective you need $a_1$, $a_2\in A$ with $a_1\ne a_2$ and $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$. That's impossible unless $A$ has at least two elements.

Comment: There is a mistake in your definition of injective. The "$\forall x \in Y$" bit needs to read "$\forall y \in X$".

Comment: @MarkKamsma, fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when you want to ask if a function $f: A \to Y$ is injective, you need to specify the function. For example, the question "is $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ injective?" is not a good question, because it depends on $f$. That is, $f(x) = x$ is injective (the obvious inclusion), but $f(x) = 0$ is not (a constant map).

That being said, because you want $A$ to be empty your question is actually well-defined. That is because for any set $Y$ there is only one function $\emptyset \to Y$. That is the empty function, let's call it $e$.

As mentioned in the comments, the empty function is always injective. We have to check whether for all $x$ and $y$ in the domain we have that $e(x) = e(y)$ implies $x = y$. Well, there is not much to check, in fact we have nothing to check at all! So that statement is automatically true because there is nothing to check, we call this *vacuously true*.

The above argument works for any set $Y$, so in particular for $Y = \mathcal{P}(\emptyset)$.

Comment: question how did you arrive at,"()=()  implies ="?

so let for all x is e(x) but does the empty set have no elements how would e(x) appear. Or we using the definition to get e(x) = e(y) implies x = y. That's where I am confused.

Comment: @EM4 I did not arrive at "$e(x) = e(y)$ implies $x=y$", I said that that is what we have to check. So for any $x, y$ in the domain, then we need to check that "if $e(x) = e(y)$ then $x=y$". However, we never arrive at the stage where we need to check "if $e(x) = e(y)$ then $x=y$" because our domain is empty, and so there is no $x$ or $y$ in there.

Comment: oh okay, it makes sense :) 

so my proof was correct but with typo in my definition of injective. Me using $f \subset A \times \mathcal{P}(A)$ does it show us it is injective cause it is empty anyways?